# Deleting Cookies with Varnish

Tags: varnish, setcookie, varnish-vcl

I have the following VCL:

```
sub jamie_fetch
{
    if(beresp.http.X-Var-Cache == "YES") {
        unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
        set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "YES";
        set beresp.grace = 365d;
        set beresp.ttl = 365d;

        return(deliver);
    }

    set beresp.http.X-Cacheable = "NO";

    return(hit_for_pass);
}
```

I know it partly works because I get the following header when I first visit the page:

```
X-Cacheable:YES
```

However I also get:

```
Set-Cookie:foobar
```

I am assuming I have made a mistake in the following:

```
unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
```

But from my searching that seems to be correct? I'd be grateful if someone with more experience can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance for any help/tips/pointers :-)

Comment: In all our VCL files we lowercase the header in `unset` calls. However I can't remember, and can't find, anything which definitively says this would cause your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should lower-case header names when using `unset`:

```
unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
```